# What is the Python way of doing a \G anchored parsing loop?

Tags: python, regex

What follows is a perl function I wrote years ago.  It is a smart tokenizer that recognizes some instances of things being stuck together that maybe shouldn't be.  For example, given the input on the left, it divides the string as shown on the right:

> ```
> abc123  -> abc|123
> abcABC  -> abc|ABC
> ABC123  -> ABC|123
> 123abc  -> 123|abc
> 123ABC  -> 123|ABC
> AbcDef  -> Abc|Def    (e.g. CamelCase)
> ABCDef  -> ABC|Def    
> 1stabc  -> 1st|abc    (recognize valid ordinals)
> 1ndabc  -> 1|ndabc    (but not invalid ordinals)
> 11thabc -> 11th|abc   (recognize that 11th - 13th are different than 1st - 3rd)
> 11stabc -> 11|stabc
> ```

I'm now doing some machine learning experimentation, and I'd like to do some experiments that use this tokenizer.  But first, I will need to port it from Perl to Python.  The key to this code is the loop that uses the \G anchor, something which I hear does not exist in python.  I've tried googling for how this is done in Python, but I am not sure what exactly to search for, so I'm having trouble finding an answer.

How would you write this function in Python?

```
sub Tokenize
# Breaks a string into tokens using special rules,
# where a token is any sequence of characters, be they a sequence of letters, 
# a sequence of numbers, or a sequence of non-alpha-numeric characters
# the list of tokens found are returned to the caller
{
    my $value = shift;
    my @list = ();
    my $word;

    while ( $value ne '' && $value =~ m/
        \G                # start where previous left off
        ([^a-zA-Z0-9]*)   # capture non-alpha-numeric characters, if any
        ([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)   # capture everything up to a token boundary
        (?:               # identify the token boundary
            (?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])       # next character is not a word character 
        |   (?=[A-Z][a-z])         # Next two characters are upper lower
        |   (?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])    # lower followed by upper
        |   (?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]) # letter followed by digit
                # ordinal boundaries
        |   (?<=^1(?i:st))         # first
        |   (?<=[^1][1](?i:st))    # first but not 11th
        |   (?<=^2(?i:nd))         # second
        |   (?<=[^1]2(?i:nd))      # second but not 12th
        |   (?<=^3(?i:rd))         # third
        |   (?<=[^1]3(?i:rd))      # third but not 13th
        |   (?<=1[123](?i:th))     # 11th - 13th
        |   (?<=[04-9](?i:th))     # other ordinals
                # non-ordinal digit-letter boundaries
        |   (?<=^1)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)st)       # digit-letter but not first
        |   (?<=[^1]1)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)st)    # digit-letter but not 11th
        |   (?<=^2)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)nd)       # digit-letter but not first
        |   (?<=[^1]2)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)nd)    # digit-letter but not 12th
        |   (?<=^3)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)rd)       # digit-letter but not first
        |   (?<=[^1]3)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)rd)    # digit-letter but not 13th
        |   (?<=1[123])(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)th)   # digit-letter but not 11th - 13th
        |   (?<=[04-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])(?!(?i)th)   # digit-letter but not ordinal
        |   (?=$)                               # end of string
        )
    /xg )
    {
        push @list, $1 if $1 ne '';
        push @list, $2 if $2 ne '';
    }
    return @list;
}
```

I did try using re.split() with a variation on the above.  However, split() refuses to split on a zero-width match (an ability that should be possible if one really knows what one is doing).

I did come up with a solution to this specific problem, but not to the general problem of "how do I use \G based parsing" - I have some sample code that does regexes within loops that are anchored using \G and then in the body it uses another match anchored at \G to see which way to proceed with the parse.  So I'm still looking for an answer.

That said, here is my final working code for translating the above to Python:

```
import re

IsA                 = lambda s: '['  + s + ']'
IsNotA              = lambda s: '[^' + s + ']'

Upper               = IsA( 'A-Z' )
Lower               = IsA( 'a-z' )
Letter              = IsA( 'a-zA-Z' )
Digit               = IsA( '0-9' )
AlphaNumeric        = IsA( 'a-zA-Z0-9' )
NotAlphaNumeric     = IsNotA( 'a-zA-Z0-9' ) 

EndOfString         = '$'
OR                  = '|'

ZeroOrMore          = lambda s: s + '*'
ZeroOrMoreNonGreedy = lambda s: s + '*?'
OneOrMore           = lambda s: s + '+'
OneOrMoreNonGreedy  = lambda s: s + '+?'

StartsWith          = lambda s: '^' + s
Capture             = lambda s: '('    + s + ')'
PreceededBy         = lambda s: '(?<=' + s + ')'
FollowedBy          = lambda s: '(?='  + s + ')'
NotFollowedBy       = lambda s: '(?!'  + s + ')'
StopWhen            = lambda s: s
CaseInsensitive     = lambda s: '(?i:' + s + ')'

ST                  = '(?:st|ST)'
ND                  = '(?:nd|ND)'
RD                  = '(?:rd|RD)'
TH                  = '(?:th|TH)'

def OneOf( *args ):
  return '(?:' + '|'.join( args ) + ')'

pattern = '(.+?)' + \
  OneOf( 
    # ABC | !!! - break at whitespace or non-alpha-numeric boundary
    PreceededBy( AlphaNumeric ) + FollowedBy( NotAlphaNumeric ),
    PreceededBy( NotAlphaNumeric ) + FollowedBy( AlphaNumeric ),

    # ABC | Abc - break at what looks like the start of a word or sentence
    FollowedBy( Upper + Lower ),

    # abc | ABC - break when a lower-case letter is followed by an upper case
    PreceededBy( Lower )  + FollowedBy( Upper ),

    # abc | 123 - break between words and digits
    PreceededBy( Letter ) + FollowedBy( Digit ),

    # 1st | oak - recognize when the string starts with an ordinal
    PreceededBy( StartsWith( '1' + ST ) ),
    PreceededBy( StartsWith( '2' + ND ) ),
    PreceededBy( StartsWith( '3' + RD ) ),

    # 1st | abc - contains an ordinal
    PreceededBy( IsNotA( '1' ) + '1' + ST ),
    PreceededBy( IsNotA( '1' ) + '2' + ND ),
    PreceededBy( IsNotA( '1' ) + '3' + RD ),
    PreceededBy( '1' + IsA( '123' )  + TH ),
    PreceededBy( IsA( '04-9' )       + TH ),

    # 1 | abcde - recognize when it starts with or contains a non-ordinal digit/letter boundary
    PreceededBy( StartsWith( '1' ) ) + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( ST ),
    PreceededBy( StartsWith( '2' ) ) + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( ND ),
    PreceededBy( StartsWith( '3' ) ) + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( RD ),
    PreceededBy( IsNotA( '1' ) + '1' ) + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( ST ),
    PreceededBy( IsNotA( '1' ) + '2' ) + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( ND ),
    PreceededBy( IsNotA( '1' ) + '3' ) + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( RD ),
    PreceededBy( '1' + IsA( '123' ) )  + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( TH ),
    PreceededBy( IsA( '04-9' ) )       + FollowedBy( Letter ) + NotFollowedBy( TH ),

    # abcde | $ - end of the string
    FollowedBy( EndOfString )
  )

matcher = re.compile( pattern )

def tokenize( s ):
  return matcher.findall( s )
```

Comment: For Python, I think the `\G` anchor is in the experimental `regex` module. A fyi - a lot of those regex subexpressions can be combined into a single expression.

Comment: What do you mean, they can be combined?  Can you give me a specific example?

Comment: Let me test it out for a while.

Comment: Right off the bat, there is a problem. This `( [a-zA-Z0-9]*? )` is going to match nothing if it can. Since some of your token boundary assertions satisfy the _nothing_ that it matched, the engine will bump the search position by 1 character without consuming anything. This will happen all it can, until none of the assertions except `(?=$)` is satisfied, and forces `( [a-zA-Z0-9]*? )` to match the remaining letters/numbers.

Comment: This code works...in Perl.  I'm not asking for help with the regex, only help with how this idiomatic programming style is accomplished in Python

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using multi-line mode. Isn't there a way other than the \G anchor?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is split a string without throwing away any of the characters in it.  I have well-defined boundary conditions I want to split on.  I didn't think of doing this using "split" originally.  But I tried using it in Python, but it won't work because the (lacking foresight) Python developers thought that people shouldn't want to do this.

Comment: Ah, you know, with all those assertions, split() should be your best bet, does it support regex?

Comment: Like I said, try out Python's new _`regex`_ module, it supports the \G anchor.

Comment: Post that as an answer (with an example code that works, even if it is a much simpler regex) and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I don't know Python, but here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex is where to find the new module. Use browser find for `\G` Search anchor. You could just setup a test case. Use import 'regex' instead of 're'

Comment: Are you just running this code on those individual small text samples, or are you trying to find such combinations by running the regex on a larger text that may contain many matching bits to be split?

Comment: I have 180k+ reviews of products on Amazon.  I'm tokenizing the text according to my own tokenizing rules.  I've actually added rules above and beyond what is posted above.  The code works great.  But the original question, of which this was just an example, still stands: if I couldn't find a way to do what I needed to do without \G, how would I do it WITH \G?

Comment: You can directly dump the regex in Perl into Python, except that `\G` can be emulated with [`re.RegexObject.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match). You need to keep track of the position and avoid infinite loop yourself (if your pattern can match zero-length string)

Answer (score 3):

### Emulate `\G` at beginning of a regex with `re.RegexObject.match`

You can emulate the effect of `\G` at the beginning of a regex with `re` module by keeping track of and providing the starting position to [`re.RegexObject.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match), which forces the match to begin at the specified position in `pos`.

```
def tokenize(w):
    index = 0
    m = matcher.match(w, index)
    o = []
    # Although index != m.end() check zero-length match, it's more of
    # a guard against accidental infinite loop.
    # Don't expect a regex which can match empty string to work.
    # See Caveat section.
    while m and index != m.end():
        o.append(m.group(1))
        index = m.end()
        m = matcher.match(w, index)
    return o
```

### Caveat

A caveat to this method is that it doesn't play well with regex which matches empty string in the main match, since Python doesn't have any facility to force the regex to retry the match while preventing zero-length match.

As an example, `re.findall(r'(.??)', 'abc')` returns an array of 4 empty strings `['', '', '', '']`, whereas in PCRE, you can find 7 matches `['', 'a', '', 'b', '', 'c' '']` where the 2nd, 4th, and 6th matches start at the same indices as the 1st, 3rd and 5th matches respectively. The additional matches in PCRE are found by retrying at the same indices with a flag which prevents empty string match.

<sup>I know the question is about Perl, not PCRE, but the global matching behavior should be the same. Otherwise, the original code couldn't have worked.</sup>

Rewriting `([^a-zA-Z0-9]*)([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)` to `(.+?)`, as done in the question, avoids this issue, though you might want to use [`re.S`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) flag.

### Other comments on the regex

Since case-insensitive flag in Python affects the whole pattern, the case insensitive sub-patterns have to be rewritten. I would rewrite `(?i:st)` as `[sS][tT]` to preserve the original meaning, but go with `(?:st|ST)` if it's part of your requirement.

Since Python supports the [free-spacing mode with `re.X` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X), you can write your regex similar to what you did in Perl code:

```
matcher = re.compile(r'''
    (.+?)
    (?:               # identify the token boundary
        (?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])       # next character is not a word character 
    |   (?=[A-Z][a-z])         # Next two characters are upper lower
    |   (?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])    # lower followed by upper
    |   (?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]) # letter followed by digit
            # ordinal boundaries
    |   (?<=^1[sS][tT])         # first
    |   (?<=[^1][1][sS][tT])    # first but not 11th
    |   (?<=^2[nN][dD])         # second
    |   (?<=[^1]2[nN][dD])      # second but not 12th
    |   (?<=^3[rR][dD])         # third
    |   (?<=[^1]3[rR][dD])      # third but not 13th
    |   (?<=1[123][tT][hH])     # 11th - 13th
    |   (?<=[04-9][tT][hH])     # other ordinals
            # non-ordinal digit-letter boundaries
    |   (?<=^1)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![sS][tT])       # digit-letter but not first
    |   (?<=[^1]1)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![sS][tT])    # digit-letter but not 11th
    |   (?<=^2)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![nN][dD])       # digit-letter but not first
    |   (?<=[^1]2)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![nN][dD])    # digit-letter but not 12th
    |   (?<=^3)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![rR][dD])       # digit-letter but not first
    |   (?<=[^1]3)(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![rR][dD])    # digit-letter but not 13th
    |   (?<=1[123])(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![tT][hH])   # digit-letter but not 11th - 13th
    |   (?<=[04-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])(?![tT][hH])   # digit-letter but not ordinal
    |   (?=$)                               # end of string
    )
''', re.X)
```