# Matching a list of elements to a string in no order

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match multiple elements to a single string with little to no luck. 
 
The regex should return all the elements that are in the **token** array, as many times as they occur in the string in the same order they occur, this would be a basic lexing algorithm for a very basic C compiler.

Is there a way i could transform my array to a working pattern where the elements are essentially unordered? I have not found any other patterns that could work in my case as the elements of my array could appear anywhere in the string.

```
file = """
int main() {
    return 2;
}"""

tokens = ['{', '}', '\(', '\)', ';', "int", "return", '[a-zA-Z]\w*', '[0-9]+']

def lex(file):
    results = []
    for i in tokens:
        r = re.match(r".?"+i+".",file)
        if r != None:
            results.append(r.group())
    return r
```

the output should be something like this:

```
r = ["int", "main", "(", ")", "{", "return", "2", ";", "}"]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would not suggest using a regular expression to parse source code.

Comment: I would use something to parse it into an abstract syntax tree instead.

Comment: Your arrays would be easier to read if you inserted a space after each comma.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark This isn't parsing; it's looking for the tokens that the parser would use to build the AST. Regular expressions are commonly used for tokenization.

Comment: What about https://ideone.com/eHN0g0? Based on [What is the Python way of doing a \G anchored parsing loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126909/3832970). Basically, doing [this](https://regex101.com/r/YpSgPN/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the solution from [*What is the Python way of doing a `\G` anchored parsing loop*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34126909/3832970) you can use

```py
import re
file = """
int main() {
    return 2;
}"""
 
tokens = ['{','}',r'\(',r'\)',';',"int","return",r'[a-zA-Z]\w*','[0-9]+']
p = re.compile(fr"\s*({'|'.join(tokens)})")
 
def tokenize(w, pattern):
    index = 0
    m = pattern.match(w, index)
    o = []

    while m and index != m.end():
        o.append(m.group(1))
        index = m.end()
        m = pattern.match(w, index)
    return o
 
print(tokenize(file, p))
# => ['int', 'main', '(', ')', '{', 'return', '2', ';', '}']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eHN0g0). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YpSgPN/1).

Basically, this matches any of the patterns in the `tokens` list *consecutively* after zero or more whitespaces starting from the start of the string.

This also means you must have a complete set of token patterns that might appear in the input, else, this will stumble at non-matching text.